# R Factor Analysis with factanal() for huge amount of predictors results in a system that is computationally singular

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am trying to run Factor analysis for a dataset with around 150 variables but only have around around 80 observations.
I tried the `factanal()` function in R and R reported error:

> Error in solve.default(cv) :
> system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.0804e-20

Any suggestions on alternative methods / packages?

A demonstration on a dummy dataset would be:

```
# This will work (dataset with 80 obs and 15 predictors)
set.seed(1234)
fake_df = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80*15), nrow = 80))
factanal(fake_df, factors = 2, rotation = "varimax")

# This will not (dataset with 80 obs and 150 predictors)
set.seed(1234)
fake_df = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80*150), nrow = 80))
factanal(fake_df, factors = 2, rotation = "varimax")
```

So far I've replaced the solve function in the `factanal()` source code  with a numerical solving function one that I created below, but it did not resolve the issue:

```
solve_G = function(M){
  library(matrixcalc)
  if(!is.singular.matrix(M)){
    return(solve(M))
  } else{
    s = svd(M)
    U = s$u
    V = s$v
    D_Inv = diag(1/s$d)
    Num_Inv = V %*% D_Inv %*% t(U)
    cat("Singular Matrix! SVD Used.\n")
    return(Num_Inv)
  }
}
```

And after you replace "solve" with "solve_G", a new error occurred:

> Error in factanal.fit.mle(cv, factors, start[, i], max(cn$lower, 0), cn$opt) :
> could not find function "factanal.fit.mle"

P.S. Here is the new "factanal" function named my_factanal:
The error above occurred when running the line:

```
nfit <- factanal.fit.mle(cv, factors, start[, i], max(cn$lower, 0), cn$opt)
```

And to run this, Set x to be a 80* 150 numerical dataframe, set `factors = 2, set scores = "regression", rotation = "varimax"`:

```
my_factanal = function (x, factors, data = NULL, covmat = NULL, n.obs = NA, 
                        subset, na.action, start = NULL, scores = c("none", "regression", 
                                                                    "Bartlett"), rotation = "varimax", control = NULL, ...) 
{
  sortLoadings <- function(Lambda) {
    cn <- colnames(Lambda)
    Phi <- attr(Lambda, "covariance")
    ssq <- apply(Lambda, 2L, function(x) -sum(x^2))
    Lambda <- Lambda[, order(ssq), drop = FALSE]
    colnames(Lambda) <- cn
    neg <- colSums(Lambda) < 0
    Lambda[, neg] <- -Lambda[, neg]
    if (!is.null(Phi)) {
      unit <- ifelse(neg, -1, 1)
      attr(Lambda, "covariance") <- unit %*% Phi[order(ssq), 
                                                 order(ssq)] %*% unit
    }
    Lambda
  }
  cl <- match.call()
  na.act <- NULL
  if (is.list(covmat)) {
    if (any(is.na(match(c("cov", "n.obs"), names(covmat))))) 
      stop("'covmat' is not a valid covariance list")
    cv <- covmat$cov
    n.obs <- covmat$n.obs
    have.x <- FALSE
  }
  else if (is.matrix(covmat)) {
    cv <- covmat
    have.x <- FALSE
  }
  else if (is.null(covmat)) {
    if (missing(x)) 
      stop("neither 'x' nor 'covmat' supplied")
    have.x <- TRUE
    if (inherits(x, "formula")) {
      mt <- terms(x, data = data)
      if (attr(mt, "response") > 0) 
        stop("response not allowed in formula")
      attr(mt, "intercept") <- 0
      mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
      names(mf)[names(mf) == "x"] <- "formula"
      mf$factors <- mf$covmat <- mf$scores <- mf$start <- mf$rotation <- mf$control <- mf$... <- NULL
      mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
      mf <- eval.parent(mf)
      na.act <- attr(mf, "na.action")
      if (.check_vars_numeric(mf)) 
        stop("factor analysis applies only to numerical variables")
      z <- model.matrix(mt, mf)
    }
    else {
      z <- as.matrix(x)
      if (!is.numeric(z)) 
        stop("factor analysis applies only to numerical variables")
      if (!missing(subset)) 
        z <- z[subset, , drop = FALSE]
    }
    covmat <- cov.wt(z)
    cv <- covmat$cov
    n.obs <- covmat$n.obs
  }
  else stop("'covmat' is of unknown type")
  scores <- match.arg(scores)
  if (scores != "none" && !have.x) 
    stop("requested scores without an 'x' matrix")
  p <- ncol(cv)
  if (p < 3) 
    stop("factor analysis requires at least three variables")
  dof <- 0.5 * ((p - factors)^2 - p - factors)
  if (dof < 0) 
    stop(sprintf(ngettext(factors, "%d factor is too many for %d variables", 
                          "%d factors are too many for %d variables"), factors, 
                 p), domain = NA)
  sds <- sqrt(diag(cv))
  cv <- cv/(sds %o% sds)
  cn <- list(nstart = 1, trace = FALSE, lower = 0.005)
  cn[names(control)] <- control
  more <- list(...)[c("nstart", "trace", "lower", "opt", "rotate")]
  if (length(more)) 
    cn[names(more)] <- more
  if (is.null(start)) {
    start <- (1 - 0.5 * factors/p)/diag(solve_G(cv))
    if ((ns <- cn$nstart) > 1) 
      start <- cbind(start, matrix(runif(ns - 1), p, ns - 
                                     1, byrow = TRUE))
  }
  start <- as.matrix(start)
  if (nrow(start) != p) 
    stop(sprintf(ngettext(p, "'start' must have %d row", 
                          "'start' must have %d rows"), p), domain = NA)
  nc <- ncol(start)
  if (nc < 1) 
    stop("no starting values supplied")
  best <- Inf
  for (i in 1L:nc) {
    nfit <- factanal.fit.mle(cv, factors, start[, i], max(cn$lower, 0), cn$opt)
    if (cn$trace) 
      cat("start", i, "value:", format(nfit$criteria[1L]), 
          "uniqs:", format(as.vector(round(nfit$uniquenesses, 
                                           4))), "\\n")
    if (nfit$converged && nfit$criteria[1L] < best) {
      fit <- nfit
      best <- fit$criteria[1L]
    }
  }
  if (best == Inf) 
    stop(ngettext(nc, "unable to optimize from this starting value", 
                  "unable to optimize from these starting values"), 
         domain = NA)
  load <- fit$loadings
  if (rotation != "none") {
    rot <- do.call(rotation, c(list(load), cn$rotate))
    load <- if (is.list(rot)) {
      load <- rot$loadings
      fit$rotmat <- if (inherits(rot, "GPArotation")) 
        t(solve_G(rot$Th))
      else rot$rotmat
      rot$loadings
    }
    else rot
  }
  fit$loadings <- sortLoadings(load)
  class(fit$loadings) <- "loadings"
  fit$na.action <- na.act
  if (have.x && scores != "none") {
    Lambda <- fit$loadings
    zz <- scale(z, TRUE, TRUE)
    switch(scores, regression = {
      sc <- zz %*% solve(cv, Lambda)
      if (!is.null(Phi <- attr(Lambda, "covariance"))) sc <- sc %*% 
          Phi
    }, Bartlett = {
      d <- 1/fit$uniquenesses
      tmp <- t(Lambda * d)
      sc <- t(solve(tmp %*% Lambda, tmp %*% t(zz)))
    })
    rownames(sc) <- rownames(z)
    colnames(sc) <- colnames(Lambda)
    if (!is.null(na.act)) 
      sc <- napredict(na.act, sc)
    fit$scores <- sc
  }
  if (!is.na(n.obs) && dof > 0) {
    fit$STATISTIC <- (n.obs - 1 - (2 * p + 5)/6 - (2 * factors)/3) * 
      fit$criteria["objective"]
    fit$PVAL <- pchisq(fit$STATISTIC, dof, lower.tail = FALSE)
  }
  fit$n.obs <- n.obs
  fit$call <- cl
  fit
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example dataset? Why are you rewriting source code? Can you start with a simplified example where your factor analysis DOES work and start from there?

Comment: I'd suggest running a correlation and removing columns that show extreme correlations with other columns. Your data matrix is probably not linearly independent.